# Can I somehow tell the browser if I want to open a tab in background mode or not in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser-tabs

I can see only one way. There is an option to open new tab in a background or not. Can I change it with addons / key modifiers? For example Alt + Click opens a new tab in a background. Middle click opens and focuses a new tab.

Comment: By default, Middle Click opens the link in a new tab in the background and Shift+Middle Click opens it and focuses on it.

Comment: @tomer-godinger I would mark it as an answer =) Never tried Shift + Middle click (only Left click) *\*facepalm\**

Comment: I added it as an answer so you can close the question. =) I just started trying modifiers with mouse different clicks to find it, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, <kbd>Middle Click</kbd> opens the link in a new tab in the background and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Click</kbd> opens it and focuses on it.